# Deployed next js application is not fetching updated data form mogoDB

Tags: next.js, deployment, fetch, vercel

I'm using the App router and I deployed my application on Vercel but when I make changes to the data on DB then it's not fetching the updated data.

File:adminHome/page.jsx

```
const fetchAllData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/dashboard`, { method: "GET", },{ cache: 'no-store' }); 
        const data = await response.json();
        if (response.ok) {
          setOrdersData(data.allOrders)
          setProductsData(data.allProducts)
          setUsersData(data.allUsers)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } finally {
        setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllData();
  }, []);
```

File: api/dashboard/route.js

```
import connectMongo  from '@/database/db.js'
import OrderModal from '@/models/orders'
import ProductModal from '@/models/product'
import UserModal from '@/models/user'

export const GET = async () => {
    try {
        await connectMongo()

        const allOrders = await OrderModal.find({},{paymentStatus:1});
        const allProducts = await ProductModal.find({},{genre:1, platform:1});
        const allUsers = await UserModal.find({},{googleAccount:1, isAdmin:1});

        return new Response(JSON.stringify({
            allOrders: allOrders,
            allProducts : allProducts,
            allUsers: allUsers
        }), { status: 200 })

    } catch (error) {
        return new Response("Error in get in favourites route", { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

File: /database/db.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

let isConnected = false; // track the connection

const connectMongo = async () => {
  mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

  if(isConnected) {
    console.log('MongoDB is already connected');
    return;
  }

  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.LOCALDB_MONGO, {
      dbName: "game_store",
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })

    isConnected = true;

    console.log('MongoDB connected')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

}

export default connectMongo
```

Problem :
allUsers array has 7 documents in DB & I added 1 more but the deployed version is only fetching 7.

When I run my application locally with npm run dev I'm getting 8 documents.

I don't why it's working locally but not on the deployed version.

My code is the same in GitHub and local, I have checked it multiple times.

Am I mistaken somewhere?